# Is it possible to validate a URI pathparam is empty or not using Spring or boot?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need to know whether it would be possible to validate the pathvariable value in REST URI.

Example:http://loacalhost:8080/config/test/{id}/plan

if the request comes as http://loacalhost:8080/config/test//plan without id i need to throw exception like id is must.Is it possible to do that.solution is appreciable

Answer (score 1):

It already is required by default, and an exception already is thrown if it's missing. From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html#required--):

> `public abstract boolean required`
>   
>   
> Whether the path variable is
>   required.
> **Defaults to true, leading to an exception being thrown if
>   the path variable is missing in the incoming request**. Switch this to
>   false if you prefer a null or Java 8 java.util.Optional in this case.
>   e.g. on a ModelAttribute method which serves for different requests.

Emphasis mine

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Optional`:

```
@GetMapping("/config/test/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> doGet(@PathVariable("id") Optional<Integer> id) {
    Integer idValue = id.orElseThrow(new IllegalArgumentException("Id is required"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need mark the parameter like "required" in your endpoint method